# I'm not receiving response from API when making a post request

Tags: ios, swift, api

I'm not getting an exact response from API call as I have accurately posted the data and I using breakpoints I've figured out the error is at getting the response.

```
@IBAction func onTapContinue(_ sender: UIButton) {
    registerData["otp_code"] = codeTextField.text
    print("Registration Check \(registerData)")
   apiCall()
    
}

extension VerificationCodeVC {
    func apiCall (){
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://admin.sapid.mx/api/register") else {
            print("Error: cannot create URL")
            return
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/jason", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
       
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:  registerData, options: .fragmentsAllowed)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _ ,error in
            guard let data = data , error == nil else {
                return
            }
                        do {
                let response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
                print("success:\(response)")
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
            
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear. Do you enter the closure? Is `guard let data` called? Do you enter the else? Can you print `data`? `error` and also the ommitted parameter `_`? Who calls `apiCall()`?

Comment: apiCall() is called by UIbutton in the main class. yes, I've used closure and I can print `data` @Larme

Comment: You can print `data`? Then what's the issue? Is `print("success:\(response)")` or ` print(error)` getting called? What's the output in console then?

Comment: `print("success:\(response)")` is called and in the output in the console is ` email field is required ` while the in `print(data)` email is printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below line to set `Content-Type`, it should be `application/json` instead of `application/jason`.

```
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Also check, It must have included `NSAppTransportSecurity` in info.plist file.

[Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

Comment: For what use NSAppTransportSecurity, if the author uses "https"?

Comment: @sergey_s if the author uses "https" no need to include NSAppTransportSecurity. I added in answer because of precautionary purpose if there is insecure("http") request.